# How to turnoff oracle 12c LISTENER Security [ON: Local OS Authentication]

Tags: security, oracle12c

[ON: Local OS Authentication]->[OFF] in oracle 12c

Answer (score 3):

Local OS Authentication can be disabled by setting the LOCAL_OS_AUTHENTICATION_
parameter in listener.ora file as such –

```
LOCAL_OS_AUTHENTICATION_<listener> = OFF
```

Comment: A full file example would be usefull

Comment: @Bato-BairTsyrenov It is the same used since Oracle 10G (default). This will help you https://avdeo.com/tag/local_os_authentication/